# Change the Y axis range based on the selected data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a chart done in the D3. It works but I would like to add the ability of the axis scaling.

I have several sets of data that have a completely different range.
So I would like the Y axis range to be altered according to the selected series.

This is the entire code: https://plnkr.co/edit/89ERO3GuxREvYQ3DRX5L?p=preview

For the moment the example linked has 4 series: I would like that if for example the user selects "Kiwi" and "Apple" then the Y axis has range [0-1] and not [0-15] (or something like that). 
The important thing is that the range is changed according to the selected data.

An example of what I mean is http://bl.ocks.org/andrewleith/3824854.

To do so I thought to save in an array the tags that have opacity 0.5 or 1 (the visible lines) and then according to that change the domain Y.
I created the array, and then I tried to identify the tag with opacity 0.5 (for simplicity) in this way:

```
var actives = new Array();
var activeElem = d3.select(".line").attr("opacity", 0.5);
console.log(activeElem);
```

or

```
var actives = new Array();
var activeElem = d3.selection.style({opacity: "0.5"});
console.log(activeElem);
```

or

```
var actives = new Array();
var activeElem = d3.selectAll("path[opacity='0.5']");
console.log(activeElem);
```

None of these works.
I also did other tests but I don't remember exactly what, and still did not work.
I am going crazy.

What is the right way to select items with opacity 0.5 and 1 and change the Y-axis based on the selected data?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi the main issue here is that you need to make another calculation of the min and max values of your data and afterwards update your yAxis with the new domain with the min and max values.

```
// find the new max value of the selected series
var max = d3.max(filteredData, function(d) {
    return d3.max(d.values, function(e) {
      return e.value;
    });
});
// find the new min value of the selected series
var min = d3.min(filteredData, function(d) {
    return d3.min(d.values, function(e) {
        return e.value;
    });
});
// set the new y domain
y.domain([min, max]);
// update our new y axis with the new domain
svg.selectAll("g .y.axis").transition()
    .duration(800).call(yAxis);
```

Since you want to filter your data by selecting certain lines I recommend using the `data` function which will allow you to join the specified array of data with the current selection (more info [here](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/)). You are making a huge `forEach` loop when you could be using the d3 utilities. Something in the lines of:

```
// apend a group element which will contain our lines
svg.append('g')
   .attr('class', 'line-container')
   .selectAll('.normal-line-paths')
   .data(dataNest) // set our data
   .enter() // enter the data and start appending elements
   .append('path')
   .call(path); // calling our path function for later use when appending lines
```

I modified your code to use a more document driven approach, you can click on the labels and the y axis will be scaled accordingly t the new min and max values of the filtered dataset. I left the dashed group in blank so you can try and code the remaining parts and understand the logic behind the data join.

https://plnkr.co/edit/Wso0Gu4yHkdsHhl8NY8I?p=preview

EDIT:

Here is the plnkr with the dashed lines :)

https://plnkr.co/edit/yHGGtrLXZyyq0KpiVWYf?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, the code has changed a lot. I try to figure it out for good. Thanks so much!

Comment: Ok I tried to add the dotted part of taking the old code and inserting it in a `pathDashed` function.
This is the result https://plnkr.co/edit/r59QLTuQbpK60cdYMpHA?p=preview. 
The code doesn't work, the error is *script.js: 249 Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property 'values' of undefined*.
Sorry, even if I have watched and examinated your code, I can't change it in the right way..Could you help me? Thanks for all

Comment: Thank you so much, really. You've been very kind. It works perfectly. Thanks again and have a good day :)